# How to make a tkinter button invisible alike a hitbox. Python

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have tried finding transparent colours and making shell buttons but nothing has worked. another way I have tried is to use the different types of Relief but none have changed the change in button position when pressed.

```py
from tkinter import *
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
window = Tk()
window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
userimage = PhotoImage(file='user.png')
def make_invisible(widget):
   widget.pack_forget()
def quit():
    sys.exit()
header = Label(window, bg= "green",width=500, borderwidth=0, height=2).grid(row=0,column=1, sticky= W+E+N+S)
endbut = Button(window, activebackground= "green",height = 2, text= "X", borderwidth=0, command=quit, bg = "red", width= 3, font=('Helvetica bold', )).grid(row=0,column=0)
profilelab = Button(window, image=userimage,activebackground="green",bd=0, relief=RIDGE).place(y=-0.5, x= 1490)
profilebut = Button(window, ).pack_forget()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Its worth the note that when pressed in the button is in the correct position

Comment: You forgot to post what you tried, and in what *specific* ways it did not "work".

Comment: If you don't want it to look or act like a Button at all, then don't use a Button - use a Frame or Label, and call `.bind()` to have it respond to mouse clicks.

Comment: With the use of .bind should I create a new Frame/Label or stick with the original label?

Comment: If you want to create a  hitbox, just bind a click to the root window, then examine the coordinates of the event to however you define the hitbox. Is that what you're asking how to do?